# Use layers or invoke another lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-lambda

I have a module that maintains a connection instance to a redis server:

```
const getClient = (() => {
    let client;
    return () => {
        if (!client) client = clientFactory(); // lazy loading of the redis client
        return client;
    }
})();
```

And this module is intended to be deployed on AWS Lambda. As per [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) suggest, the redis client in the closure above shall never be destroyed manually in favour of context reuse, and will be automatically destroyed when the lambda invocation instance is killed.

Now the problem is: I have some other modules, which will also be deployed on lambda as separate lambda functions, and will need to utilize the redis client module. Should I set the redis module as a reusable layer, or should I deploy the module as yet another separate function, and directly invoke the function from the calling modules?

Concerns for using layer: the redis connection will be instantiated for every separate calling module, which is not good for context reuse.

Concerns for invoking another lambda function: network overhead.

As I understand invocation between two lambda functions, the caller will send an API request to the callee, producing extra network overhead. So will this matter more than poor context reusing?